# AngularJs with prettyprint ngView Routing issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pretty-print, angularjs-ng-route

I am using "prettyprint" along with "AngularJs" which is working very well, but only issue is if I use routing, then the prettyprint function is not working (as it might have been configured to run on pageLoad). Now, what if I am going to various ng-view pages and coming back? How to run the prettyprint function even on route change?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/prettify.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/styles/sons-of-obsidian.css">
<script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/run_prettify.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<a href="#/one">One</a>
<a href="#/two">Two</a>
<a href="#/three"> Three</a>
<div ng-view=""></div>

<script>
//App Declaration 
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'] );
//Controllers 
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
});

//Routers 
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/one', {
        templateUrl: 'one.html'
    })  
    .when('/two', {
        templateUrl: 'two.html'
    })  
    .when('/three', {
        templateUrl: 'three.html'
    })  
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/one'
    });
});
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

one.html

```
This is one
<pre class="prettyprint">
&lt;div&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;
        &lt;a href="http://www.google.com"&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
</pre>
```

two.html

```
This is two
```

Image on first time clicking 'one' link:

[image]

Going to 2nd view or 3rd view and then coming back:

[image]

> Can someone help me out please?

Comment: Why are you applying your app and controller on both the `<body>`-tag and the `<div>`-tag? This might be an issue.

Comment: Sorry, was a typo. Removed the div. The real problem persists.